# Unable to Retrieve Inline Styles and Background Images from Contentful in Angular Application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, contentful

I am working on an Angular application that fetches content from Contentful, where I have input fields to insert HTML code. My goal is to display this HTML content on my website, but I'm encountering issues with inline styles and background images.

1. I insert HTML code into Contentful input fields, including inline styles.
2. When I retrieve this content in my Angular application, it does not seem to detect or apply the inline styles. As a result, the styles are missing, and my website doesn't display the content correctly.
3. Specifically, I'm trying to set the background image of a div element using a URL from AWS S3. However, the background image is not making it to my application.

I suspect that there might be an issue with how Contentful stores and retrieves inline styles or background images. I'm using Angular to fetch and display this content.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can provide guidance on how to ensure that inline styles and background images are correctly retrieved and applied when fetching content from Contentful in an Angular application?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!